# echoing specific files, excluding some characters

Tags: unix, echo

I have a folder with a few files, mainly these 3:

```
vmware-diskmanager
VMware-disklib.tar.gz
vmware-disklib-distrib
```

If I want to echo both files without the .tar.gz extension, I can use

```
# echo v*
```

but let's say I have another file

```
VMware-disklib
```

then I could use

```
# echo [vV]*
```

to get all four files, but can I complete the command line with something that says "don't show any files with a dot in it"?

Answer (score 0):

## With bash

If you use bash, see `man bash`, *EXPANSION* > *Pathname Expansion* > *Pattern Matching*:

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.

(This option seems to be the default.) In particular you can use:

> `!(pattern-list):`
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns

So in your case this could work:

```
echo [vV]!(*.*)
```

## With `find`

I use zsh instead of bash and this does not work.
I have not checked wether there is an equivalent syntax for zsh, personally I would go for a solution with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex './v[^.]*' -exec echo -n "{} " \;
```

Where:

- `.` is the directory to search
- `-maxdepth 1` limits the search to the current directory (no recursion)
- `-iregex './v[^.]*'` applies a case-insensitive regex to whole path of files in current directory
- `-exec echo -n "{}"`  indicates to echo the file name (the name will replace the `{}` placeholder) without linebreak
- `\;` is needed to end the `-exec` command.

It should print the name of your files with `./` at the beginning and without linebreak at the end. But on the plus side, you can use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete the command line by saying "don't show any files with a dot in it". You need to escape (use a backslash) before the dot:

```
# echo [vV]* | grep -v "\."
```